Regular Expresssion find Comma in Redshift Database
I have a query which is having , in lname column. I want to find the , and replace it with blank. I want to use regex_substr but not getting any solution.
As of now i am able to resolve this using replcae function :
replace(lname,',','') as lname

I am newly learning regex. Can you please help me ?

According to Amazone-redshift documentation, REGEXP_REPLACE function definition is:
REGEXP_REPLACE( source_string, pattern [, replace_string [ , position [, parameters ] ] ] )

Which pattern is same as other type of SQL REGEX_REPLACE function and describe as follows:

So, your answer should be:
select REGEXP_REPLACE('Tri,m all comma, fr,om inp,ut text,', ',', '', 1, 0);

It should work in Amazone-redshift DB.
MySQL sample solution:
db<>fiddle

Thanks a lot for the detailed answer. I want to search for single character whether lower or upper case or if there is a single digit or any other special characters. can i do it in this way.
REGEXP_REPLACE(lname, '[^a-zA-Z0-9]', '', 1)

For upper or lower case there already have match_type option. use that.

For more details you may follow this page: https://medium.com/@artbindu/how-to-use-regex-in-mysql-5ab60a43a883
